# How to convert yyyy-mm-dd to yyyymmdd in where clause of SQL select command

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

The format in the database for date column is `yyyymmdd` but my code in aspx.cs passes the parameter value as `yyyy-mm-dd`. How can I convert `yyyy-mm-dd` to `yyyymmdd` in the `WHERE` clause if my select statement?

`aspx.cs` code:

```
adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select distinct a.e_id from tenter where  (date='" + Convert(DateTime.Value.ToString()) + "')", myConn);
```

Comment: Learn to use **parametrized queries** - for one, those protect your code from **SQL injection** (which is the #1 vulnerability out there on the web), and secondly, they allow you to pass a date **as a DATE** (and not mangled as a string) and this avoids needing to convert the date back and forth between string representations!

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyymmdd");` ?

Answer (score 4):

Please don't save your `DateTime` values as a character.

Type your `date` column as a [`datetime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) or [`datetime2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) and pass your `DateTime.Now` value directly to your [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). Otherwise, it will be open for [SQL Injectio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)n attacks.

Read: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

As an example;

```
using(var myConn = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = myConn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "select distinct a.e_id from tenter where date = @date";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(@date, SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = DateTime.Now;
    using(var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
       // Do your operations.
    }
}
```

Also `date` might [reserved word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in future releases of SQL Server. You *might* need to use it as `[date]` as well.

Answer (score 0):

It may helps you

You can use this logic and work on your query

```
 declare @a date= '2014/2/3'
 select replace(@a,'-','')
```

Answer (score 0):

use SQL CAST()

```
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection=con;
cmd.CommandText="select distinct a.e_id from tenter where cast(date as date)=cast(@date as date)";
cmd.Paramenter.AddWithValue("@date",Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Value));
```

Comment: You have too many syntax error in your code. And saving a `DateTime` value as a character **always** a bad idea.

Comment: yes, upper and lower case combination. isn't it??@SonerGönül

Answer (score 0):

```
adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand ("select distinct a.e_id from tenter where (date='" + DateTime.ParseExact(("2015-03-18"), "yyyy-MM-dd", null).ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "')", myConn);
```

Comment: Sorry but saving a `DateTime` value as a character **always** a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much to all of you. 
The best answer for me like this:-
adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand ("select distinct a.e_id from tenter where  (date='" + startdate.Value.ToString().Replace("-",string.Empty) + "')", myConn);

Comment: Don't post your own answer here, mark one of the answers as accepted. (In this case the one @ZwoRmi posted, as bad as it might be)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe simply : `DateTime.Value.ToString().Replace("-",string.empty)`

Comment: First of all, it is `Replace` not `replace`. Second, saving your `DateTime` values as a character **always** a bad idea.

Comment: I agree with you, but you have not **always** the control of the database.

Answer (score -2):

for mysql you can try this :

> where date_format(date,'%Y%m%d') = '20150318'

@+jef

Comment: this is [sql-server] not [mysql]